# arm 32 byte move with ldm/stm as inline asm

Tags: c, gcc, arm, gcc8

I am trying to do the following and it doesnt work. The code crash with an arm toolchain gcc 8.5.

```
#define _move(src, dst) __asm volatile ( \
                "ldr   r0, [%0] \n\t"    \
                "ldr   r1, [%1] \n\t"    \
                "ldm   r0!, {r4-r11} \n\t" \
                "stm   r1!, {r4-r11} \n\t" \
                :          \
                : "r" (dst), "r" (src)          \
                : "cc"          \
                )


static uint32_t sr[8];
static uint32_t ds[8];

int main() {

    sr[0] = 0xff;
    
    _move(sr, ds);

    printf("data:%d\n", ds[0]);

}
```

What is wrong with the code?

https://godbolt.org/z/edzz9vhPK

Comment: Did you check that you can use all these registers without destroying important values? You should at least say so in the clobber list.

Comment: `ldr   r0, [%0]`, read value from `dst` address. or `r0 = ds[0]`. `ds[0]` is likely to be zero (or some random crap) and `ldm   r0!, {r4-r11}` is falling on NULL dereferencing, I reckon.

Comment: In addition to declaring clobbers for registers 4 through 11, you also need to clobber `"memory"`.

Comment: Anyhow, is there a reason you don't trust the compiler and just do `memcpy(ds, sr, 32)`?

Comment: Thanks to mention "memory". The reason for doing this is time. I need the fastest way to transfer data. At the moment I can't do dmac transfer which I do normally.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was an unaligned access because in the real project there is a buffer which starts aligned 32 but the access with ldm to the data was sometimes unaligned.

Now I check the src pointer before accessing them and if it is not aligned I mask the first two bits out. At the time I process the data this is checked and corrected.